# How to change imagebutton when clicking on it?

Tags: libgdx, imagebutton

I'm trying to make a sound system in LibGDX where you press an imagebutton and then that imagebutton turns into another icon like on and off sound signs. I have no idea how to make it because as soon as i create a new constructor for the imagebutton it loses the code thats inside the Listener. I have a feeling some kind of loop needs to be used here and have tried to make it work inside loops but doesn't seem to work.

here is my code:

```
musicBtn.addListener(new ChangeListener() { //musicBtn is the imageButton


               @Override
               public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {

                   if(GameManager.getInstance().gameData.isMusicOn()){//if the music is on and you press the music button then this turns it off
                       GameManager.getInstance().gameData.setMusicOn(false);
                       GameManager.getInstance().stopMusic();


                   } else {//if the music is off and players presses music button it turns on
                       GameManager.getInstance().gameData.setMusicOn(true);
                       GameManager.getInstance().playMusic();

                   }

                   GameManager.getInstance().saveData(); //method that saves the data

               }
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a Drawable to the ImageButton constructor called imageChecked:

```
ImageButton (Drawable imageUp, Drawable imageDown, Drawable imageChecked)
```

this could for example be an off sound sign. Whenever you press the button, check if the music is playing, if it is set checked to true, this will change the image to the sound off sign, otherwise set it to false and it will change back to what you had

```
if(GameManager.getInstance().gameData.isMusicOn()){
     ...
     musicBtn.setChecked(true)
}else{
    ...
    musicBtn.setChecked(false)
}
```